# Eclipselink Entity is not recognized

Tags: java, persistence, eclipselink

I have Versions which may rely on other Version. The dependent Versions are stored in the List `dependsOn`. Because I need to be able to determine, in what other Versions a specific Version is used I have the List `usedIn` which is the inverse of dependsOn.

My Problem is as soon as I add methods to add/remove a single Version from `dependsOn` EclipseLink does not recognize my class `Version` as entity anymore.

My Version class:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "tbl_version" )
@NamedQueries( /*...*/ )
public class Version extends BaseEntity
{
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable( name = "tbl_depends_on",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "PK_VERSION" ) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "PK_DEPENDENCY" ) }
    )
    private List<Version> dependsOn;

    @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "dependsOn" )
    private List<Version> usedIn;

    public void addDependency( Version dependency )
    {
        if( dependency == null )
        {
            return;
        }
        dependsOn.forEach( ( Version version) -> 
        {
            if( dependency.equals( version ) )
            {
                return;
            }
        } );
        dependsOn.add( dependency );
    }

    public void removeDependency( Version dependency )
    {
        if( dependency == null )
        {
            return;
        }
        dependsOn.forEach( ( Version version ) ->
        {
            if( dependency.equals( version ) )
            {
                dependsOn.remove( version );
                return;
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

As soon as I delete `addDependency` and `removeDependency` EclipseLink works perfect again. Also it is not the field `usedIn`, I already tried to delete it.
I am using EclipseLink 2.5 as persistence api.
Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

**Update**
The following exception is thrown

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: Version [id=null, 

name=1.2.5] is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at persistence.VersionTest.setUp(VersionTest.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Line 71 is part of a the setUp in a JUnit test:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    Version version1 = new Version();
    version1.setName( versionName1 );

    Version version2 = new Version();
    version2.setName( versionName2 );

    EntityTransaction transaction = manager.getTransaction();
    try
    {
        transaction.begin();
        manager.persist( lVersion1 ); //line 71
        //...
```

Comment: Hmm, behavior that is seemingly random. Stupid test: what if you add the methods but completely comment out the code in them? As in: what if the class contains no Java 8 lamdas?

Comment: @Gimby Many thanks, it was all about the lamdas! I replaced them with a common for loop and now it is working.

Comment: I was really hoping that this was not the case, because now I'm really wondering why the lamdas pose a problem. The latest version of EclipseLink is 2.6.0, does that make a difference? It might be that the EclipseLink bytecode instrumentation logic in your version does not understand Java 8 specific stuff yet

Comment: @Gimby It realy does a difference: Version 2.6.0 works with lambdas. I changed the version in my pom, now it is everything working like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Java 8 lambdas in your entity code, you should have an up-to-date version of EclipseLink that is Java 8 bytecode compatible or you will likely run into conflicts. Use EclipseLink version 2.6.0 or higher.

The source of the problem can be read in this bug report, which was resolved in 2.6.0:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429992

Comment: For people following this, be aware that these versions (2.6.0, 2.6.1) of EclipseLink have an issue you can easily run into when upgrading: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=463629 . Its not an application breaking issue, it will just log an annoying exception at startup.