# Java8 upgrade done from Java6 and Tomcat7.0 to Tomcat8.0 >bean creation Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-8

I'm having issue while  upgrading  **JAVA8 from Java6 and Tomcat7.0 to Tomcat8.0**. Before I'm having  Spring source suite tool development tool.  hibernate3 jar file is used I'm having below issue.

Please let me know which hibernate jar files it will support and other jar files?

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'desecn' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'itracProps' while setting bean property 'icProps';
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'itracProps' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed;
>
> nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException.

WEB-INF/Application-context.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE beans
        PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>


    <!-- COMMON CLASS -->

    <bean id="desecn" class="com.appfoundation.itrac3.misc.DesEncrypter">
        <property name="icProps" ref="icProps" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="utility" class="com.appfoundation.itrac3.misc.Utility">
        <property name="icProps" ref="icProps"/>
        <property name="desecn" ref="desecn"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Precept Migration - init method is placed to get Servlet Context from Spring Web Application Context -->
    <bean id="icProps" class="com.appfoundation.itrac3.misc.ItProperties" init-method="loadProperties"/>
```

Comment: Full stack trace may help.

Comment: Also doing an upgrade of 2 java versions is likely to break things, especially if you don't upgrade frameworks. Especially hibernate 3 (which isn't tested on java8) and older versions of spring.

Comment: Especially Hibernate or any other ORM package since they do bytecode manipulation. That was actually the resolution of a very simular question about EclipseLink yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308784/eclipselink-entity-is-not-recognized/

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'desecn' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'itracProps' while setting bean property 'itracProps'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itracProps' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: /**application context.xml file */        
<bean id="desecn class="com.appfoundation.itrac3.misc.DesEncrypter">
   <property name="itracProps" ref="itracProps" />
  </bean> 
  
  <bean id="utility" class="com.appfoundation.itrac3.misc.Utility">
   <property name="itracProps" ref="itracProps"/>
   <property name="desecn" ref="desecn"/>
  </bean>

Comment: <!-- Precept Migration - init method is placed to get Servlet Context from Spring Web Application Context -->
  <bean id="itracProps" class="com.appfoundation.itrac3.misc.ItracProperties" init-method="loadProperties"/>

Comment: hi..im not able to upload full stack trace ..i just uploaded main contents.as per client suggestion...we upgraded java8 and tom8

Comment: If you would just edit it into your question, you'd have more success.